# Cheapest way to dissipate energy (discharge battery)

Tags: energy, watts

What is the cheapest way to burn a lot of energy? Say I want to burn 800W (4V, 200A). How should I do that?

Ugly suggestions like: use a pot of water and a cable are welcome :)

It should be easy and cheap..

Comment: What do you mean by "burn energy"? Energy is never created nor destroyed, only transformed (assuming we don't get into mechanisms where \$E=m·c^2\$ could make a difference). You want to transform energy into heat?

Comment: @Telaclavo: yes, transform it into heat. Without destroying any components like resistors or whatever..

Comment: I think it will be better if you tell us the ultimate purpose of what you want to do.

Comment: @Telaclavo: discharge a battery cell which is around 4V.

Comment: I don't think what you're doing is smart. You should look into switch mode converters. You are most likely looking to reduce the voltage of a circuit.

Comment: +1 I don't know why someone downvoted. The question is good, and the answer, not trivial.

Comment: BTW, I just remembered. You can not only passively, but also *actively* remove energy from it. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/31580/9137

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can see why. You don't "burn" energy. The OP also didn't explain the application or purpose. Is the point to make heat or to be a electronic load? And what's the point of mentioning a pot and water, and what does a cable have to do with that. All around, it's a poorly written question.

Comment: @OlinLathrop the idea of the pot of water is to create an immense short circuit with smoke and light and fingers all around :)

Comment: @clabacchio: Actually 4V applied to ordinary water won't do much of anything unless the electrodes are large and/or very close.

Comment: @OlinLathrop right :) I always forget the 4V

Comment: @duedl0r Are you planning to ever use the battery again, like try to recharge it?  Discharging even at ordinary rates (say less than 1C) will damage the battery if it's allowed to discharge to below the cutoff voltage, and may render it useless.  Draining a battery to zero volts through power resistors (or salt water, steel beam, etc.) and leaving it that way for a while is going to kill it, with or without power transistors to make the current nice and smooth.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: the pot of water is for cooling.. and the wire for making a short circuit..

Comment: @MattB. that depends entirely on the type of battery. NiCd batteries allow you to discharge it to 0V. Of course you have to be careful if you use lithium batteries.

Comment: Burn energy would imply just dump it into thermal energy to me. Pretty useless to an EE unless you do thermoelectrics.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you want a dummy load that can dissipate 800 W.  Normally I use incandescent light bulbs for things like this.  They have some nice properties:

Are designed to handle the heat.

Are cheap and plentiful, so a combination at the desired power can usually be found.

Are self-indicating.  You know when they are on or off just by looking.

However, there are two problems with this.  Incandescent light bulbs are getting less and less available nowadays, and are even banned in some cases.  4 V is also a difficult voltage for dissipating significant power.  Even 12 V automotive bulbs aren't going to dissipate significant power at 4 V.

So in the end you probably end up with a bunch of power resistors in parallel.  The big fat ceramic wire wound types can do this.

There are also things called *electronics loads*.  Those are nice, often dump the power back onto the power line, but are expensive.

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to kill you battery, [Isabellenhütte](http://www.isabellenhuette.de/en/resistance-alloys/) may be of help. They're known for very low resistance resistors (milliohms), but they also supply resistive alloy to resistor manufacturers. Maybe they can supply you with some bulk material.

Other solution: [this MOSFET](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD%2FFDL100N50F.pdf) will sink 100A. Place a number of them parallel, fix them on a big block of steel, which you hold under water in the river. You'll have to drive the FET with a higher voltage than 4V.

Comment: MOSFETs are good for controlling energy but rather expensive for dissipating that energy. I'd rather do so in a resistor switched on and off by a MOSFET.

Comment: @Jason - The MOSFET will keep the current constant for a longer time. The resistor will cause the current to decay with voltage.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't do it: the battery may explode. First check the maximum discharge rate of your battery.

But if you REALLY want to harm yourself (or someone else), a small-value (fractions of Ohm) high-power resistor may work. And clearly Olin's solution allows to obtain low values with higher power ratings :)

This solution will be cheaper, excluding the cost of the battery and your house :)

Comment: Yes.  @duedl0r Tell us more about the battery (chemistry, capacity) before putting a crowbar across its terminals ;) .  How quickly do you wish to discharge the battery?  (Please refrain from saying "as quickly as possible.)  By the way, the ratings you provide in the body of your message are related to power (Watts), but the title deals with energy (which would be in Joules).

Answer (score 3):

I had to do something like this a number of years ago. I would agree with Olin for the most part (incandescent light bulbs are ridiculously cheap, and they light up when powered), but light bulbs have the disadvantage that their resistance changes significantly between cold and hot, and to get 800W you're going to either have to purchase a bunch of them and wire in parallel, or find some very large bulbs.

The best way we found for a cheap dissipative load is a heating element. You can get a hot plate with a spiral burner for under $20. Heat or boil water, and you basically never have to worry about it overheating.

The tough part here is matching to the voltage. AC loads are meant for rms voltages of 120VAC or 220VAC (or others) depending on your location, and if you have an rms load of 80-100V that would work ok with a 120VAC load. But a 4V load isn't going to dissipate much power in anything intended for AC. You could try to look for water heating elements that are in the 6-12V range -- if you search for  "low voltage submersible heating element" you should find a bunch of 12V but I haven't found any reputable vendors of 6V elements.

Do the math for a bunch of cheap power resistors in parallel (as Olin said) from Digikey -- if you can't find a single heating element that will beat that in cost/availability/ease of use, go for the power resistor approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add just one minor detail that appears (at least to me) to getting overlooked here. To draw 200 amps from a 4 volt source, your load has to be 0.02 ohms (R = E/I). If you start with, say, 1 ohm resistors, you'll still need 50 of them in parallel to get the right resistance, and each will need to be (at least) a 16-watt resistor to carry the load. You could start with (for example) 50 watt 0.2 ohm resistors to reduce the number/work involved, but either way it's not going to be particularly cheap.

Depending on exactly what temperature you're willing to tolerate, you'd need something like 2 to 4 gauge copper wire to carry a 200 amp load safely. Unfortunately, at that size you also get pretty low DC resistance so you'd be looking at something like one to two hundred feet of it to get the proper resistance -- still not what you'd usually call cheap.

Steel has enough higher resistance (and lower price) than copper that I'd guess something like steel pipe or I-beam would get you to the right resistance range for a *lot* less money. You'd probably be looking at something like an 8 or 10 foot section of something like 4 or 6 inch I-beam/pipe (though there are a lot of steel alloys with different resistance, so you'll pretty much have to measure to find the right length).

This has the added benefit of a fairly large surface area for the cross section. You almost certainly want to submerge it to keep the temperature reasonable, and the large surface area will help make the submersion more effective.